# How could I stop this vba loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro to loop my steps across all worksheets in the workbook as below.
However, it appears an error:

Run-time error '1004':
"Select method of Worksheet class failed"

```
Sub WorksheetLoopFormat()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim i As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For i = 2 To WS_Count

        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("C:C,G:G,I:I,AN:AN").Select
        Range("AN1").Activate
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("C30").Select
        Sheets(i).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

     Next i

  End Sub
```

Hope there would be someone help me!!
Many thanks!!

Comment: You need to seriously rewrite your code :) [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Transform Workbook

- Copies a range of not contiguous columns of each (source) worksheet
  to a newly added (target) worksheet and then deletes the source
  worksheet and renames the target worksheet to the name of the source
  worksheet.
- Only **work**sheets that are not in the **Exception List** will be
  processed. The program will **not** fail if there are **charts** in
  the workbook.
- In the **easy** version, you have to be careful **not to run the
  program twice**, because you won't like the result. This is prevented
  in the **advanced** version.

### Easy

```
Sub WorksheetLoopFormatEasy()

    Const cExc As String = "Sheet1"             ' Worksheet Exception List
    Const cSrc As String = "C:C,G:G,I:I,AN:AN"  ' Source Range Address
    Const cTgt As String = "A1"                 ' Target Cell Range Address
    Dim wsS As Worksheet  ' Source Worksheet
    Dim wsT As Worksheet  ' Target Worksheet
    Dim vntE As Variant   ' Exception Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Exception Array Element (Name) Counter
    Dim strS As String    ' Source Worksheet Name

    ' Copy Exception List to Exception Array.
    vntE = Split(cExc, ",")

    ' In This Workbook (i.e. the workbook containing this code.)
    With ThisWorkbook
        ' Loop through all Source Worksheets.
        For Each wsS In .Worksheets
            ' Loop through elements (names) of Exception Array.
            For i = 0 To UBound(vntE)
                ' Check if current name in exception array equals the current
                ' Worksheet name.
                If Trim(vntE(i)) = wsS.Name Then Exit For ' Match found
            Next
            ' Note: Exception Array is a zero-based one-dimensional array.
            ' If a match is NOT found, "i" will be equal to the number of
            ' names in Exception Array (i.e. UBound(vntE) + 1).
            If i = UBound(vntE) + 1 Then
                ' Add a new worksheet (Target Worksheet) after Source Worksheet.
                ' Note:   The newly added worksheet will become the ActiveSheet
                '         and will become the Target Worksheet.
                .Sheets.Add After:=wsS
                ' Create a reference to Target Worksheet.
                Set wsT = .ActiveSheet
                ' Copy Source Range to Target Range.
                wsS.Range(cSrc).Copy Destination:=wsT.Range(cTgt)
                ' Write source worksheet name to Source Worksheet Name.
                strS = wsS.Name
                ' Delete Source Worksheet.
                ' Note:   Disabling DisplayAlerts suppresses showing
                '         of the 'delete message box'.
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wsS.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                ' Rename Target Worksheet to Source Worksheet Name.
                wsT.Name = strS
            End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "The program has finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

### Advanced

```
Sub WorksheetLoopFormatAdvanced()

    Const cExc As String = "Sheet1"             ' Worksheet Exception List
    Const cSrc As String = "C:C,G:G,I:I,AN:AN"  ' Source Range Address
    Const cTgt As String = "A1"                 ' Target Cell Range Address
    Dim wsS As Worksheet  ' Source Worksheet
    Dim wsT As Worksheet  ' Target Worksheet
    Dim vntE As Variant   ' Exception Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Exception Array Element (Name) Counter
    Dim lngA As Long      ' Area Counter
    Dim lngC As Long      ' Source Range Columns Count(er)
    Dim strS As String    ' Source Worksheet Name
    Dim strA As String    ' ActiveSheet Name

    ' Speed up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' Handle Errors.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Copy Exception List to Exception Array.
    vntE = Split(cExc, ",")

    ' In This Workbook (i.e. the workbook containing this code.)
    With ThisWorkbook

        ' Write the name of ActiveSheet to ActiveSheet Name.
        strA = .ActiveSheet.Name

        ' Loop through all Source Worksheets.
        For Each wsS In .Worksheets

            '*******************************'
            ' Prevent Double Transformation '
            '*******************************'

            ' Calculate Source Range Columns Count if not already calculated.
            If lngC = 0 Then
                ' Loop through Areas of Source Range.
                For lngA = 1 To wsS.Range(cSrc).Areas.Count
                    ' Count the columns in current area.
                    lngC = lngC + wsS.Range(cSrc).Areas(lngA).Columns.Count
                Next
                ' Check if number of used columns in Source Worksheet is equal
                ' to the number of columns of Source Range.
                If wsS.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, _
                        xlPrevious).Column - wsS.Range(cTgt).Column + 1 _
                        <= lngC Then GoTo DoubleTransformationError
            End If

            '*****************
            ' Transform Data '
            '*****************

            ' Loop through elements (names) of Exception Array.
            For i = 0 To UBound(vntE)
                ' Check if current name in exception array equals the current
                ' Worksheet name.
                If Trim(vntE(i)) = wsS.Name Then Exit For ' Match found
            Next
            ' Note: Exception Array is a zero-based one-dimensional array.
            ' If a match is NOT found, "i" will be equal to the number of
            ' names in Exception Array (i.e. UBound(vntE) + 1).
            If i = UBound(vntE) + 1 Then
                ' Add a new worksheet (Target Worksheet) after Source Worksheet.
                ' Note:   The newly added worksheet will become the ActiveSheet
                '         and will become the Target Worksheet.
                .Sheets.Add After:=wsS
                ' Create a reference to Target Worksheet.
                Set wsT = .ActiveSheet
                ' Copy Source Range to Target Range.
                wsS.Range(cSrc).Copy Destination:=wsT.Range(cTgt)
                ' Write source worksheet name to Source Worksheet Name.
                strS = wsS.Name
                ' Delete Source Worksheet.
                ' Note:   Disabling DisplayAlerts suppresses showing
                '         of the 'delete message box'.
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wsS.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                ' Rename Target Worksheet to the name of Source Worksheet.
                wsT.Name = strS
            End If
        Next

    End With

    MsgBox "The program has finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcedureExit:

    ' Activate worksheet that was active before program execution.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strA).Activate

    ' Speed down.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

DoubleTransformationError:
    MsgBox "The program has already run.", vbInformation, _
            "Double Transformation Prevention"
    GoTo ProcedureExit

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has  occurred. Error '" & Err.Number & "': " _
            & Err.Description, vbInformation, "Error"
    GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
```

### Remarks

The newly added worksheets will have the same names as their predecessors but will have different code names.

---

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion all the below could help you built a well structure code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws
            Debug.Print .Name
        End With

    Next

  End Sub

Sub AddSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    ws.Name = "Test"

End Sub

Sub Copy_Paste()

    Sheet1.Range("A1:D1").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1:D1")

End Sub

Sub DeleteSheet()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Delete

End Sub
```